# Book of calculus

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

Sometimes I want to test the concepts of calculus in practice, but the most popular books like Thomas/Maurice is   a  little approach to me.Does someone know a book that works with calculus in practice (more than Pearson's books, contextualized problems...)

Comment: A physics text?

Comment: Have you gone through Stewart?

Comment: Look for "Applied Calculus" or Calculus for Scientific/Science or Engineering titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the physics text idea. Although any calculus based text should work, I especially like "Fundamentals of Physics" by Halliday, Resnick, and Walker. While I'm sure there are other even better texts out there, this one is a great introductory text with plenty of interesting exercises. Gauss's Law and electric fields come to mind.

Comment: Math, for Physics i use the Pearson's book (Sears).